# mapView inside cardview not load the map

Tags: android

My mapView inside the `CardView` does not load until I tap on the mapView(around 8 times for finish load of the full map)

Check my Pic. The 1st card view I tapped for 8 times. The second one I didn't tap and it does not load anything

[image]

**Some of my card_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="4dp"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true" >
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">
    
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_image"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />    
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Some of my RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;

    }   


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
        viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[i]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);

        viewHolder.mp.onCreate(null);
        viewHolder.mp.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                double lat1 = Double.parseDouble("1.344376");
                double lng1 = Double.parseDouble("103.862162");
                LatLng bord = new LatLng(lat1, lng1);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bord).title("Marker on board"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(bord, 13.0f));
             }
        });
        viewHolder.mp.postInvalidate();

    }
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Share your layout file

Comment: your java file pls.

Comment: Try to change the zoom level of your map view at the time of loading map.

Comment: @FYS you can paste the layout code as well as your java file's code here, so that somecan point out your mistake.

Comment: Just add pls check it.

Comment: @FYS Remove this line and try again : mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

Comment: @FYS One more thing : remove android:clickable="true" from your root tag of <CardLayout> and add it inside mapview <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>. Hope it helps.

Comment: make zoom level 18

Comment: The problem still exists. How I can refresh the mapView manually ? I thought that might work.

Answer (score 0):

look at the sample for using lite Map at RecyclerView.

sample - https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java

Check carefully "constructor" "onMapReady" "bind" "onViewRecycled" methods